# Print IntelliJ IDEA Effective System Properties

Tags: intellij-idea

There are different ways setting system properties of IntelliJ IDEA, e. g. `idea.plugins.path`, described [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207240985-Changing-IDE-default-directories-used-for-config-plugins-and-caches-storage) (mainly `idea.properties` files). I got a support case where plugins path seems to be set to a different location. I looked through all these properties files but couldn't find any "wrong" information.

Is there a way to print system properties used by IntelliJ IDEA? Just like *Help* > *Settings Summary*.

Comment: Currently it's not possible.

Comment: Okay, that's too bad, but thank you.

Comment: Feel  free to create feature request on YouTrack: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.